# Why doesn't my code respond elsewise?

Tags: python, sockets, localhost

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 1600))
sock.listen(1)
(client_sock,client_address) = sock.accept()
client_name = client_sock.recv(1024)
client_sock.send('hi its '+client_name)
client_sock.close()
sock.close();
```

So i run on cmd command prompt the file containing the code above, and all i get is this:
[image]

As it can be seen my cmd is as if waiting for something to happen, it doesnt print out "Hi its ..." and never ends from waiting.
Why doesn't my code work ?

Comment: Are you sending anything to it?

Comment: It blocks at `recv()` so the "Hi its" never got sent.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple: you have first to send the data and then receive. The receive command wait until the timeout (if it is set) and then go over. Remember that you have also to print the received data. 
The best practice for doing what you want to do is a server-client approach having at least two different threads.